# Where comes this Fatal error from? cakephp phpunit

Tags: testing, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I created a cakephp3 project with composer.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app foobar
```

Then, I baked a helper with

```
bin/cake bake helper Progress
```

And copypasted the helper-example in the cakephp [testing tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html)
Switching in the directory and performing `phpunit` says

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addWarning) in /home/matthias/www/isbn.localhost/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php on line 173
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:42
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:138
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:186
PHP   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration() /home/matthias/www/foobar/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:145
PHP   6. require_once() /home/matthias/www/foobar/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:771

Fatal error: Class Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addWarning) in /home/matthias/www/foobar/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php on line 173

Call Stack:
    0.0001     225152   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0031     515440   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:42
    0.0031     516064   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:138
    0.6384    6931096   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:186
    0.6384    6932312   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration() /home/matthias/www/foobar/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:145
    0.6458    7043088   6. require_once('/home/matthias/www/foobar/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php') /home/matthias/www/foobar/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:771
```

Doesn't matter if the global installed phpunit 4.2.6 or the latest version, installed with composer, is used. Where comes this from and how to can I fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use a global PHPUnit installation when you have one that is local to your CakePHP installation, as you can see this will conflict, look at the stacktrace, you're starting in `/usr/bin/phpunit`, and then it jumps into `/home/matthias/www/foobar/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/...`.

That being said, you seem to have installed the "wrong" PHPUnit version in your CakePHP app, the mentioned method `addWarning` was introduced with PHPUnit 5.1 alpha! The whole 5.x branch is not yet stable, and CakePHP <strike>is not yet compatible to it</strike> was just recently [**updated**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7355) (not yet released) to support the changes, so for now you should install the stable 4.x branch instead, like

```
$ composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~4.0
```

Unfortunately the `prefer-stable` option (which is by default set to `true` in the CakePHP app skeletons `composer.json`) doesn't seem to help here, as Composer will choose ~5.1@dev when not specifying a version on your own (even if it's just `*`).

Comment: Works perfekt! Thanks.

Comment: @MatthiasMoritz I just saw that [**CakePHP was updated**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7355) a few hours ago to support the PHPUnit changes. Still, if you don't really have a specific reason to use the unstable 5.x branch, you're better off with the stable 4.x one.